# HTML + JS. Как по нажатию кнопки вывести переменную из функции js в текстбокс html

Tags: javascript, html

Вот текстбокс, куда нужно вывести переменную.

```
Вывод <input type = "text" name = "target"   value = "">
```

Вот некая функция, которая ищет минимальный элемент массива, массив берет из другой функции, нужно вывести min в текстбокс по нажатию кнопки.

```
function getMinValue(array){
    var min = arr[0];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (min > arr[i]) min = arr[i];
    }
    return min;
}
```

Вот как я пытался это реализовать, не работает(

```
<input type="button" value="Вывод min "onclick="document.getElementById('target').innerHTML=min">
```

Понимаю, вопрос очень глупый, но что поделать, я только учусь..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

на скорую руку

```js
let arr = [10,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

function getMinValue(array){
    var min = arr[0];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (min > arr[i]) min = arr[i];
    }
    return min;
}

document.getElementById("button").addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  document.getElementById('min').value = getMinValue(arr);
})
```

```html
Вывод <input type = "text" name = "target"   value = "" id="min">

<input type="button" value="Вывод min" id="button">
```

Comment: Спасибо, вы мне очень помогли!

Answer (score 0):

Вижу несколько ошибок:

1. У Вас `getMinValue` принимает параметр с названием `array`, но использует почему-то `arr`, которого нет внутри области видимости функции.
2. Вы берете поле по ID но в атрибутах у него есть только `name` нет `id`.

Это мне кажется, основные причины неполадок. Ну и оформите то, что делаете по onclick в отдельную функцию.